# Winforms - listbox Get the object from the selected item in the list

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm new to Winforms and would like some help.

I'm trying to get the selected object from a list of item and use it on a when a button is clicked.

The problem seams to be that I don´t know to get the selectedItem object in a correct way.

Can anyone help me sort this out?

```
// fist I will add the object to a list like this:
petList.Add(new Dog(animalName));

// Then I will retrieve the last item and add it to the listbox:
var addedPet = petList.Last();
AnimalList.Items.Add($"{addedPet.GetType().Name} {addedPet.AnimalName} Lycka: {addedPet.Happiness} Trötthet: {addedPet.Tierdness} Hunger: {addedPet.Hungriness} ");

// When I have a selected item I would like to be able to click a button and execute 
private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string resultText = "Inget djur valt från listan, vänligen välj ett djur.";

    // I believe the error occurs here:  
    // When I step in the code I can see that "pet" is NULL but I have the string that was added to the list.
    Animal pet = AnimalList.SelectedItem as Animal;

    if (pet != null) 
    {
        resultText = pet.Play();
        MessageBox.Show($"Du har nu lekt med {pet.AnimalName}");
    }

    TextBoxOutPut.Text = resultText;
}
```

Comment: The `ListBox` `AnimalList` looks like it is filled with `strings` and NOT  `Animal` objects. Therefore the line of code … `Animal pet = AnimalList.SelectedItem as Animal;` … fails because it can’t cast a `string` to an `Animal`. I am confident the `ListBox` should contain `Animal` objects so the cast will succeed.

Comment: Yes, you were right. problem solved.